# Outdoor Outlet Non-GFCI Downstream of GFCI

Tags: electrical, gfci

Can I run a non-gfci outlet outside if it is downstream from a GFCI outlet on the same circuit?

Comment: Where is this GFCI located?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can do that, using the LOAD side of the GFCI.

But not only **can** you do it, it is actually a **very good idea**. That is because GFCI includes sensitive electronics not in a regular receptacle. Keeping a GFCI clean and dry and temperature controlled will likely make it last much longer than it would outside.

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can.

If the downstream outlet is fed from the GFCI receptacle's LINE terminals, it will not have GFCI protection.

If it's fed from the GFCI recep's LOAD terminals, it will have GFCI protection.

Intending to protect downline loads is the only valid purpose of the LOAD terminals. They should not be used for any other purpose.

Comment: And this is still the case even if the non-gfci is outdoors?

Comment: @Dylan The GFCI requirement is satisfied by being downstream, whether you mean outside or next to a sink

Comment: @Dylan you misunderstand.  There is no requirement for GFCI *receptacles* anywhere in Code.  They are not needed at all.  What is needed is GFCI protection, and that can be on the load lines of a GFCI breaker, deadfront, switch, recep, whatever that is upstream.

Answer (score 1):

"And this is still the case even if the non-gfci is outdoors?"

Yes, anything that's downstream on that circuit will be GFCI protected regardless of whether its located indoors or outdoors. As long as you continue the circuit from the LOAD side, just like what the last person said.